# How can I use mod_rewrite to link SEO friendly multilingual URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Good day. I am trying to map an URL like "sitename.com/lang-code/pagename" to pagename.php?lang=lang-code using mod_rewrite, so I made this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.+)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
...
```

The thing is, I get an error when trying to change the language of the site. I'm not using a framework, so the file structure of my project has one main folder where are the views(index, about_us, contact, etc.), and a set of subfolders for Db, css, js, etc. I developed the multilingual site using this article: http://techbrush.org/simplest-way-to-create-a-multilingual-website/

Testing solutions, I find out that if I created a folder with the name 'lang-code' I could "solve" the error but what I really want if a rewrite rule that can tell Apache to don't read the 'lang-code' in "sitename.com/lang-code/pagename" as a folder. Can anyone help me with this? Tyvm in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule most likely doesn't execute. You are checking if `lang` exists in the query string, and only then read the first part of the path and use that as a language instead. That doesn't make sense.

You can improve this by checking if `lang` does **not** exist in the query string, and only match languages your site actually supports. For example, `css` and `js` are no languages, even though you might have those folders to put your stylesheets and javascript files in. Besides that, if the url contains a query string it is currently overwritten. You probably want to use the `[QSA]` flag to append the new query string to the current query string.

Your new rule would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de)/(.+)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```